# Offset groupby difference by one row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
first   client   last_visit   theme_type   days_borrowed
----------------------------------------------------------
Y       A        4/23/2019    Candy        0
N       A        5/5/2019     Jewel        12               
N       A        5/8/2019     Chocolate    3         
N       A        6/2/2019     Candy        25
N       A        6/12/2019    Rock         10
Y       B        3/5/2019     Chocolate    0
N       B        3/5/2019     Rock         0
Y       C        2/6/2019     Rock         0
Y       D        1/30/2019    Jewel        0
N       D        2/4/2019     Rock         5
N       D        2/8/2019     Candy        4
```

The days_borrowed column is calculated by:

```
df['days_borrowed'] = df.groupby('client')['last_visit'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0)
```

However, I need it to actually take the difference in reverse, if that makes sense, since the # days borrowed is actually for the prior theme, not the current theme. The last theme selection should calculate to the difference of the last_visit and a static date (e.g., 7/31/2019).

Thus, the desired output looks like this:

```
first   client   last_visit   theme_type   days_borrowed
----------------------------------------------------------
Y       A        4/23/2019    Candy        12
N       A        5/5/2019     Jewel        3              
N       A        5/8/2019     Chocolate    25         
N       A        6/2/2019     Candy        10
N       A        6/12/2019    Rock         49
Y       B        3/5/2019     Chocolate    0
N       B        3/5/2019     Rock         148
Y       C        2/6/2019     Rock         175
Y       D        1/30/2019    Jewel        5
N       D        2/4/2019     Rock         4
N       D        2/8/2019     Candy        173
```

Where the 49, 148, 175, and 173 were calculated by taking the difference from last_visit and the fixed date of 7/31/2019.

So I was wondering if was possible to:

1) Offset the difference calculation by 1, and

2) For the last occurrence for each client, to have it take the difference between last_visit and a fixed date (7/31/2019)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `-1` for the `periods` argument of [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) then take the absolute value.
2. `fillna` with your desired calculation.

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
#df['last_visit'] = pd.to_datetime(df.last_visit)

df['days_borrowed'] = (df.groupby('client')['last_visit']
                         .diff(-1).dt.days.abs()
                         .fillna((pd.to_datetime('2019-07-31')-df['last_visit']).dt.days))
```

#### Output: `df`

```
   first client last_visit theme_type  days_borrowed
0      Y      A 2019-04-23      Candy           12.0
1      N      A 2019-05-05      Jewel            3.0
2      N      A 2019-05-08  Chocolate           25.0
3      N      A 2019-06-02      Candy           10.0
4      N      A 2019-06-12       Rock           49.0
5      Y      B 2019-03-05  Chocolate            0.0
6      N      B 2019-03-05       Rock          148.0
7      Y      C 2019-02-06       Rock          175.0
8      Y      D 2019-01-30      Jewel            5.0
9      N      D 2019-02-04       Rock            4.0
10     N      D 2019-02-08      Candy          173.0
```

Comment: This is incredible -- worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! If you're certain everything will be an integer you can also add `downcast='int64'` as an argument to `fillna`.